# GEE: How to sort ImageCollection correctly by system:index

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, sorting

I am very new to GEE and I have the following Problem:
I have to create NDVI time series (with MODIS Vegetation indices) and compare the monthly mean value between 2001 and 2021 with the monthly mean in 2022.

Everything worked fine, after computing the monthly mean I had two ImageCollections with 12 images each. Then I tried to subtract the 2022 time series from the other to get the NDVI difference. The subtraction works, but the order of the images is broken.

Order before subtracting: `0, 1, 2, 3, .... 10, 11`

Order after subtracting: `0, 1, 10, 11, 2, 3, ...`

I don't know how to fix this because maybe I don't really understand how the data structure of the objects/images in GEE works.
I also don't understand why the ImageCollections before I subtracted them were sorted correctly even if there was no leading zero in system:index (the labels in the time series are the same in the inspector) but after subtracting this(?) was suddenly a problem.

I already tried to create a new property with the value of the system:index and insert a leading zero to indices 0-9 but it seems that the value is neither a regular string nor a number so it doesn't do what I want.

```js
var ndviReference = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD13A2").filterDate('2001-01-01', '2021-12-31').select('NDVI')

var ndvi2022 = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD13A2").filterDate('2022-01-01', '2022-12-31').select('NDVI')


var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);

var ndvi2022byMonth = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      months.map(function (m) {
        return ndvi2022.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                    .select(0).median()
                    .set('month', m);
}));

var ndviReferencebyMonth = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      months.map(function (m) {
        return ndviReference.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                    .select(0).median()
                    .set('month', m);

var ndviDiffboth = ndvi2022byMonth.combine(ndviReferencebyMonth)
var ndviDiffsubtracted = ndviDiffboth.map(function(img){
  var ndvi = img.select(0).subtract(img.select(1))
  return ee.Image([ndvi])
})
```

Comment: So your sort is in alphabetic order, not numeric. Sets are generally not ordered. Did you try sorting them?

Comment: I tried it with .sort('system:index') but this changed nothing (it changes the generell order if I set ascending to false, so I think sorting works in general, but it stays sorted alphabetic). Are there any other ways to sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by the `month` property:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/b42362a66d2a451ab2d7b99cdd74fe16

```js
var ndviReference = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD13A2").filterDate('2001-01-01', '2021-12-31').select('NDVI')
var ndvi2022 = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD13A2").filterDate('2022-01-01', '2022-12-31').select('NDVI')

var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);
print("Months: ", months)


var ndvi2022byMonth = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      months.map(function (m) {
        return ndvi2022.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                    .select(0).median()
                    .set('month', m);
}))
.sort("month");

print("Order in ndvi2022byMonth",ndvi2022byMonth.aggregate_array("system:index"))

var ndviReferencebyMonth = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      months.map(function (m) {
        return ndviReference.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                    .select(0).median()
                    .set('month', m);
}))
.sort("month");
print("Order in ndviReferencebyMonth:", ndviReferencebyMonth.aggregate_array("system:index"))

var ndviDiffboth = ndvi2022byMonth.combine(ndviReferencebyMonth)
.sort("month");

print("Order in ndviDiffboth:",ndviDiffboth.aggregate_array("system:index"))  // Bands: NDVI and NDVI_1  Properties: month, and system:index

var ndviDiffsubtracted = ndviDiffboth.map(function(img){
  var ndvi = img.select("NDVI").subtract(img.select("NDVI_1"))
  return ee.Image([ndvi])
})
print("Order in ndviDiffsubtracted:", ndviDiffsubtracted.aggregate_array("system:index"))
```

Try it out with and without the `.sort(month)`. Your image collection in your original code was re-ordered even before -- just after using `.combine()`, but by using `.sorth(month)` you can specify the order you want.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem!